# How to use select statement in SQL Server on conditions

Tags: c#, sql-server

I want to filter data on conditions using combo boxes in c#, so I used this stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GET_FIXING_ON_CONDITIONS] 
    @BranchID int,
    @MachGroupID int,
    @FailGroupID int,
    @FailID int,
    @MachNo varchar(50),
    @DateFrom date,
    @DateTO date
AS
    SELECT tbBranches.BranchName,
           tbMachines.MachNo,
           tbMachines.MachType,
           tbMachinesGroups.MachGroupName,
           tbFails.FailName,
           tbFailsGroups.FailGroupName,
           tbFailsType.FailTypeName,
           tbFixing.FixDate,
           tbFixing.FixDetails,
           tbFixing.FixPerson
    FROM tbMachines
         INNER JOIN tbFixing ON tbMachines.MachNo = tbFixing.FixMachNo
                            AND tbMachines.BranchID = tbFixing.BranchID
         INNER JOIN tbFailsGroups ON tbMachines.BranchID = tbFailsGroups.BranchID
         INNER JOIN tbFailsType ON tbMachines.BranchID = tbFailsType.BranchID
         INNER JOIN tbFails ON tbFixing.FixFailID = tbFails.FailID
                           AND tbFixing.BranchID = tbFails.BranchID
                           AND tbFailsGroups.FailGroupID = tbFails.FailGroupID
                           AND tbFailsGroups.BranchID = tbFails.BranchID
                           AND tbFailsType.FailTypeID = tbFails.FailType
                           AND tbFailsType.BranchID = tbFails.BranchID
         INNER JOIN tbMachinesGroups ON tbMachines.MachGroupID = tbMachinesGroups.MachGroupID
                                    AND tbMachines.BranchID = tbMachinesGroups.BranchID
         INNER JOIN tbBranches ON tbMachines.BranchID = tbBranches.BranchID
                              AND tbFixing.BranchID = tbBranches.BranchID
    WHERE tbBranches.BranchID = @BranchID
      AND tbMachinesGroups.MachGroupID = @MachGroupID
      AND tbFailsGroups.FailGroupID = @FailGroupID
      AND tbFails.FailID = @FailID
      AND tbMachines.MachNo = @MachNo
      AND tbFixing.FixDate >= @DateFrom
      AND tbFixing.FixDate <= @DateTO;
```

Parameters are compensated by the 7 combo boxes but the problem is I have to choose (all) parameters values to display the data and this is not required,
what I want is display data once I choose (any) value from any combo box

Comment: Do you know how to execute SQL statements from C#? What have you tried so far? Do you have a default value for all of the inputs?

Comment: Yes I know, I have a button to execute  SQL statements from C#  form

Comment: You may have to share your C# code - there are lots of ways to run this type of query, so answers could be very different based on what you are already doing (Dapper vs Entity Framework vs SqlCommand ....)

Comment: `what I want is display data once I choose (any) value from any combo box`, for us to help you, you would need to include code you've tried so we can help.

Answer (score 0):

It depends what you pass in your parameters if they are not specified in your C# app. (I personally pass NULLs in such a case).

I used to use a query structure like this:

```
SELECT ...
WHERE
  (@Param1 IS NULL OR [Value1] = @Param1) AND
  (@Param2 IS NULL OR [Value2] = @Param2) AND
  ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Most generally, you would do this by passing null to any parameter which has not been set by the user and the query follows this pattern:

```
WHERE (@BranchID IS NULL OR tbBranches.BranchID = @BranchID)
AND (MachGroupID IS NULL OR tbMachinesGroups.MachGroupID = @MachGroupID)
AND ...
```